# jquery "one animation after another"

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, chaining

I am trying to animate a series of divs AFTER a previous animation has occurred.  I am trying to call .mouseenter and .mouseleave to the same divs that get animated to opacity: 1.  The first animation seems to supersede any attempt to change opacity afterward.  I am totally new to programming anything and I searched for an answer to this problem.  I tried some of the solutions that seemed to pertain to my specific problem, but a syntax error always occurred.

The code is below. I have the ineffective second attempt at opacity change (.fadeTo) commented out, but this is not the only method I attempted:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#work').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 890px','opacity':'1'}, 500);
    $('#sketchbook').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045px', 'opacity':'1'}, 550);
    $('#art').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1200', 'opacity':'1'}, 600);

    $('#bio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 600);
    $('#blog').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 550);
    $('#inspiration').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 500);
    $('#bottom_bar').animate({'margin-top':'700px', 'height': '15px'},1000);


    });

$('#about').click(function(){
    $('#bio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 890px','opacity':'1'}, 500);
    $('#blog').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045px', 'opacity':'1'}, 550);
    $('#inspiration').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1200', 'opacity':'1'}, 600)

    $('#portfolio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 800px','opacity':'0'}, 300);
    $('#sketchbook').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 810px', 'opacity':'0'}, 350);
    $('#art').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 820', 'opacity':'0'}, 400);
    });

});

//FADE IN / FADE OUT

//$('#portfolio').mouseenter(function(){
    //$(this).fadeTo(.7, 'fast');
//});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.animate has a "complete" callback, you can use that for instance.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Or use can use deferred objects http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred, it could be easier for so many chained calls.
Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/8VAZ3/ for a simple deferred code.

```
<div id="box"></div>

#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}

$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#box').animate({
       'width': '100'
       }, 200);
    $('#box').animate({
       'height': '100'
       }, 200);
    var def = $('#box').promise();
    def.done(
       function () {
          alert('done');
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but surely (a) `$('#box').animate(...)` returns `jQuery` so as a parameter passed to `.when()` you would need `$('#box').animate(...).promise()`. (b) Chained jQuery animations are automatically queued in the fx queue, so `.when(...).done(...)` is not necessary; `$('#box').animate(...).animate(...)` will suffice (if that's what the OP needs).

Comment: I'm sure that I'm going to come back to this post in a week or so and understand deferred objects and/or what you're saying in your edit, but as for now, I haven't got a clue what that means.  The complete callback did work and I am presently using that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot you are quite right about the point b), however if the 2nd function is not an animation, then it is different.
Now regarding point a) the code is fine as it is, as the animate function is already resolved.

Comment: Additionally this deferred JS code might be closer to the standard way of using it: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/8VAZ3/2/

Comment: (a) is academic if you accept (b), however you haven't grasped the point about `$('#box').animate(...)` returning jQuery. jQuery is not a promise, therefore `$.when($('#box').animate(...))` will resolve immediately, not on completion of the animation.

Comment: I'm convinced by now (I reviewed the documentation of the deferred objects after I read your comments), so I'll update the post too. I guess the original worked only because the animations were queued in the first place...